# How to I access reports programmatically in SalesForce using Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I'm trying to write an app on the SalesForce platform that can pull a list of contacts from a report and send them to a web service (say to send them an email or SMS)

The only way I can seem to find to do this is to add the report results to a newly created campaign, and then access that campaign. This seems like the long way around.

Every post I read online says you can't access the reports through Apex, however most or all of these posts were written before Version 20 of the API was released last month, which introduced a new report object. I can now programmatically access info about a report (Such as the date last run etc) but I still can't seem to find a way to access the result data contained in that report.

Does anyone know if there's a way to do that?

Comment: No idea... but how complex the report is? Probably you can easily write a SOQL query that will generate same result set and this can be sent anywhere without problems. One other option is that you might create a dashboard from this report, schedule it to run (daily?) and send results as email to some special mailbox...

Comment: no, it has to be on demand. I think I'll have to go the CSV/XLS Export route outlined here http://sfdc-heretic.warped-minds.com/2006/04/10/progmatic-access-to-salesforcecom-reports/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much research into it, I've discovered the only way to do this at the moment is indeed to scrape the CSV document. I would guess that Conga etc are using exactly this method.

We've been doing this for a while now, and it works. The only caveats are:

- Salesforce username / password /
  security token has to be shared to
  the app connecting. If the password
  changes (and by default it is changed
  every 30 days or so) the token also
  changes and must be re-entered.
- You have to know the host of the account, which can be difficult to 
  get right. For instance while most european accounts would use emea.salesforce.com to access CSV, our account uses na7 (North America 7) even though we're located in
  ireland. I'm currently sending the page host to the app and parsing it
  to calculate the correct subdomain to use, but I think there has to be a
  better way to do this.

Salesforce really needs to sort this out by supplying an API call which allows custom report results to be exported on the fly and allowing us to use OAuth to connect to it. But of course, this is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 2):

In the SalesforceSpring 11 update, it seems you can obtain more informations about the Reports:
As stated in the API for [Report](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_report.htm) and [ReportType](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_reporttype.htm), you can access via Apex the fields used in the query by the Report, reading the field "**columns**", as well as the field used to represent the filters called "**filter**".

Iterating through this objects, should allow you to build a String representing the same query of the Report. After building that string you can make a dynamic query with a Database.query(..) call.

It seems to be a little messy, but should work.. (NOT TESTED YET!)

As header states, this works only with Custom Reports!

Comment: not quite as messy as storing full Salesforce credentials for each user, logging in under their account, exporting a CSV file of the report, parsing that CSV and returning a column. I'll give this a try, thanks!

Comment: After looking into this, it appears that the Metadata API cannot be accessed from within APEX, so pretty much the same solution is required - an external application which connects in.

Comment: or use a callout from salesforce through their own API?

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify for fellow rookies who will find this, when the question was asked you could access your report data programatically, but you had to use some hacky, error prone methods.

This is all fixed, you can now access your reports via the API as of Winter '14.

Documentation here - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/index.htm

Go to town on those custom dashboards etc. Cross posted from the Salesforce Stack Exchange - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically/

Answer (score 1):

But Conga (appextremes) do this in their QuickMerge product, where the user specifies the report Id, and the apex script on the page runs the report to extract the results for a mail merge operation.

Answer (score 0):

the v20.0 API added metadata about the reports, but no way to actually run the report and obtain the results. If this is a standard report, or a report you've defined, you can work out the equivalent SOQL query for your report and run that, but if its an end user defined report, there's no way to do this.

Comment: It would be an end-user defined report unfortunately =(